# Stream - filter based on hashMap value

Tags: java, java-stream

I want to start from a collection of diploma projects and by using stream I want to get an arrayList of diploma project titles, from the students that have taken a course identified by courseId. They will also need to have passed the course with grade of 2 or higher.

I have this DiplomaProject class:

```
public class DiplomaProject{
    String title;
    ArrayList<Student> authors
}
```

Each diplomaProject can have multiple authors.

I have this Course class:

```
public class Course{
    String courseName;
    String courseId;
}
```

This Student class:

```
public class Student{
    String name;
    HashMap<Course, Integer> courseList;
    DiplomaProject diplomaProject;
}
```

The grade of the course is the Integer value of courseList.

This is my current solution, but I know it does not do what I want. I can't find a way to filter based on the value of the courseList, and I do not know how I can get the the diplomaProject titles at the end of the streams (only at the top level).

```
public static List<String> diplomaProjectTitle(List<DiplomaProject> diplomaProjects) {
        return diplomaProjects.stream()
                .map(diplomaProject -> diplomaProject.authors)
                .flatMap(students -> students.stream())
                .filter(student -> student.courseList.keySet().equals("math1001"))
                .flatMap(student -> student.courseList.keySet().stream())
                .map(student -> student.courseName)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: What do you need exactly? The titles of diploma projects whose **all** students have taken a specific course or the titles of diploma projects whose **at least one** student has taken a specific course?

Comment: It looks like you have to replace `student.courseList.keySet().equals("math1001")` with `student.courseList.containsKey(desiredCourse)` where `desiredCourse` is something like `new Course("CourseName", "CourseId")` and make sure that you have a proper implementation of hashCode/equals for `Course` class

Comment: @AddeusExMachina I need the diploma projects titles from all the students that have taken a specific course

Answer (score 1):

You are losing the info on the diploma projects with the the .map functions. What you want to do is operate within the `.filter()` functions of the first diplomaproj stream.
Therefore

```
    public List<String> diplomaProjectTitles(List<DiplomaProject> diplomaProjects) {
        return diplomaProjects.stream()
                .filter(projects -> projects.getAuthors().stream().map(Student::getCourseList)
                        //get the course matching this one (both name and id)
                        .map(c -> c.get(new Course("math101", "1")))
                        //check if that course has grade greater than the minimum
                        .anyMatch(grade -> grade>=2))
                .map(DiplomaProject::getTitle)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
```

For this to work though you would need to modify your Course class. Since you are using it within a hash map as a key, and want to get it through a custom *query* you will need to add the `hashCode()` function.

```
public class Course {
    private String courseName;
    private String courseId;

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return courseName.hashCode() + courseId.hashCode();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if(o instanceof Course oc) {
            return oc.getCourseName().equals(this.getCourseName()) && oc.getCourseId().equals(this.getCourseId());
        }
        return false;
    }
    
    //getters and setters
}
```

In order to test it I created a simple method that prepares a test case

```
public void filterStudents() {
        List<DiplomaProject> diplomaProjects = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Course> courses = new ArrayList<>();
        courses.add(new Course("math101", "1"));
        courses.add(new Course("calc101", "2"));
        courses.add(new Course("calc102", "3"));

        List<Student> students = new ArrayList<>();
        Map<Course, Integer> courseMap = Map.of(courses.get(0), 3, courses.get(1), 1);
        students.add(new Student("TestSubj", courseMap));
        Map<Course, Integer> courseMap2 = Map.of(courses.get(0), 1, courses.get(1), 3);
        students.add(new Student("TestSubj2", courseMap2));
        diplomaProjects.add(new DiplomaProject("Project1", students));
        diplomaProjects.add(new DiplomaProject("Project2", List.of(students.get(1))));

        log.info("Dimploma projects are " + diplomaProjectTitles(diplomaProjects));

    }
```

this way Project 1 will have a student with math101 with grade 3 and one with grade 1, and Project2 will have a student with math101 with grade 1. As expected, the result of the filtering method is only project1

Answer (score 0):

> I want to get a `List` of **diploma project titles**, from the students that have taken a `Course` identified by the given `courseId`. They will also need to have passed the course with `grade` of 2 or higher.

In your method `diplomaProjectTitle` you're actually **losing** the access to the titles of the diploma projects at the very beginning of the stream pipe-line because the very first operation extracts authors from the stream element.

You need to need the stream to of type `Stream<DiplomaProject>` in order to get a list of diploma project titles as a result. Therefore, all the logic needed to filter the desired diploma project should reside in the `filter()` operation.

That's how it might be implemented:

```
public static List<String> diplomaProjectTitle(List<DiplomaProject> diplomaProjects,
                                               String courseId,
                                               Integer grade) {
    return diplomaProjects.stream()
        .filter(diplomaProject -> diplomaProject.getAuthors().stream()
            .anyMatch(student -> 
                student.getCourseList().getOrDefault(courseId, 0) >= grade
            )
        )
        .map(DiplomaProject::getTitle)
        .toList();   // or .collect(Collectors.toList()) for JDK version earlier than 16
}
```

A couple of important notes:

- Avoid using `public` fields and accessing the fields from outside the class directly rather than via *getters*.
- Pay attention to the names of your method, variables, etc. The name `courseList` is confusing because it's actually **not** a `List`. This map should rather be named `gradeByCourse` to describe its purpose in a clear way.
- Leverage abstractions - write your code against interfaces. See [What does it mean to "program to an interface"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383947/what-does-it-mean-to-program-to-an-interface)
- Pay attention to the types you're working with `keySet().equals("math1001")` even IDE is capable to tell you that something is wrong here because `Set` can never be equal to a `String`.

Answer (score 0):

A step-by-step way of thinking:

We need to filter projects based on the criteria that these have at least one author (student) who has passed a specific course (courseId) with a grade >= 2 (another filter).

```
dipProjects.stream().filter(p->p.getAuthors().stream().anyMatch(s->s.getCourseList().getOrDefault(courseId,0) >= grade)).map(p->p.getTitle()).collect(Collectors.toList());
```